# Self registration failure messages for Salesforce community

Tags: community, community-builder

I have created a community login page using Salesforce community builder with self registration functionality. If a new user tries to sign up with the same details as of already existing user in the system, it raised an system generated error.

The error message is like[image]

I want to customize this error message. Is there any way to handle this?

I want to display the actual error messages which caused failure.
Like "You are a existing user, please login."

Comment: Does the account owner have a role?